# How to parse the children nodes xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing

how do I extract the "www.stackoverflow.com/one.jpg" and "some text" ?

```
<item>
<title>mytitle</title>
<link>http://www.stackoverflow/urls</link>
<description><![CDATA[<p><img src="www.stackoverflow.com/one.jpg" alt=""></p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>]]>&lt;br clear='all'/&gt;</description>
<dc:date>2014-01-17T12:10:06+00:00</dc:date>
</item>
```

my codes :

```
Element entry = (Element)nl.item(i);

Element title = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
Element url_link = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);
Element date = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("dc:date").item(0);
```

Comment: Which library are you using to parse the XML files?

Comment: my imports : import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

Answer (score 0):

Your  element contains only text, since you wrapped some of the markup in a  section (and escaped the < and > characters following it. You have to extract that text and manipulate it yourself.

Note that the contained text it HTML, not XML; there's no  tag and the  doesn't end with />. So you can't just feed that text through an XML parser a second time; you either need an HTML parser, or you have to extract those values using string manipulation. The latter is probably a better bet.

If this isn't what you intended, you need to fix whatever's producing this document.